# redirect post request from post request

Tags: node.js, express

trying to send post form request to another server.

I'm getting post request from my localhost lets say on POST /deposit

and I want later to redirect user to payment website with some kind of this data

​form to which I want user to redirect after he posts to: `localhost:3000/deposit`

```
<form action='http://testpayment.com/pay' class='redirect_form' method='post'>

<input type='hidden' name='key' value='${data.api_id}'>

<input type='hidden' name='signature' value='${data.api_secret_key}'>

<input type="hidden" name='user_id' value='${data.user_id}'>

<input type="hidden" name="payment_method" value="master_card">

<input type="hidden" name="customproduct" value='[{

"productId":"deposit-${currencyPayway.currency.code}",

"productName":"Test Product",

"productType":"fixedProduct",

"currency":"${currencyPayway.currency.code}",

"amount":${amount}}]'>

<button type='submit'>Pay</button>

</form>
```

Post route:​

```
app.post('/deposit', function(req, res) {

// some logic applies here

//redirect part ???

});
```

Any ideas how to do it?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Use case of what I'm ting to do:
Lets say we have multiply payment providers. On deposit action in any way after applying some logic we need to redirect user to payment provider website for card/account details input after which user will be redirect to my website back again by payment provider. Now front writes custom logic for all deposit methods each time. But I tries to decouple front from that stuff and handle it completely on backend and unify deposit process.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases as I know, paymant gateway works like this:

- you will create a form and as an URL you put your Payment Provider URL https://secure.paymentprovider.com/deposit
- you will create a form get the data from user, send on server side to Payment Provider, as a return you should get a SessionId, some kind of unique key and then you redirect user but with a GET method to Payment Provivder url ie. https://secure.paymentprovider.com/deposit/{token/sessionId}

Here is an example PayU - http://developers.payulatam.com/en/web_checkout/

Maybe you can attach link to Payment Provider api?

Comment: For some cases agree with you. But deposit case is just an example.

Comment: If you need data from the form you can use JS script send that data to your server and then POST for to correct one. It's just an idea.

Comment: right now it is working like this: server send some data to front and front redirects user to some website. Cons of this method is that front  have to create for each deposit method custom implementation. But if back can handle on it's own then user will just make post request and back will redirect user to payment website and after all interactions user will be redirected to my website by redirect which handles payments website.

Comment: that is the point why I tries to move redirect part to back end. And front will not write some custom implementation for each payment method.

Answer (score 0):

use `stream.pipe`

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

```
app.post('/', (req, res,next) => {
  var request   = require('request');
  var pipe      = req.pipe(request.post('localhost:3000/deposit'));
  var response  = [];

  pipe.on('data',function(chunk) {
    response.push(chunk);
  });

  pipe.on('end',function() {
    var res2 = Buffer.concat(response);
    console.log(res2);
    res.send(res2)
  });
})
```